# Loop Google map markers using Polymer

Tags: google-maps, polymer, google-maps-markers

I'm using a `<google-map>` Polymer component like this:

```
 <template>
    <google-map additional-map-options='{"mapTypeId":"hybrid"}' fit-to-markers>
       <google-map-marker latitude={{latitude}} longitude={{longitude}}
                     draggable="true" title={{title}}></google-map-marker>

     </google-map>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-map",
      ready: function () {
          this.latitude = 39.3991186;
          this.longitude = -79.5913991;
          this.title = "Marker 1"

      }
  });
</script>
```

If I have a lot of markers (more than 100 markers) such as the following, how can I loop and automatically add all markers into the map?

```
  markers: [{"lat": 35.137879, "lon": -76.5913991, "title":"Marker 1"},
             {"lat": 35.137879, "lon": -82.836914, "title":"Marker 2"},
             {"lat": 47.651968, "lon": -82.836914, "title":"Marker 3"},
              ...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over your `markers` array, you would use a [`dom-repeat` template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat) like this:

```
<google-map ...>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{markers}}">
    <google-map-marker 
        latitude="{{item.lat}}" longitude="{{item.lon}}"
        title="{{item.title}}" 
        animation="DROP">
        <h4>{{item.title}}</h4>
    </google-map-marker>
  </template>
</google-map>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JNEQGV)

Comment: @Tenz No problem :)